# build events for both release and debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-process

I have the following rule for post-build events

```
 copy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" ..\..\impld\
```

It works fine for release build but when I build in debug mode I get error

**MSB3073: The command "
copy "< path to dll>" ..\..\impld\
:VCEnd" exited with code 1.**

Problem is that though in debug mode < project_name>d.dll file is created VS still tries to copy "release" dll (without 'd'). There was no such error with VS2008, though the code was the same.

Comment: Use the Edit window for the post build command.  Click the Macros button and ensure that $(TargetFileName) has the "d".  If not then you'll have to describe what setting you used to get the "d".

Comment: It is set in project properties Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Output File

Comment: You are making me pull teeth, the macro value matters.  Using the linker option should produce a build warning.  Use General + Target Name instead.  Default is $(ProjectName), make it $(ProjectName)d instead.

Comment: More precisely I changed $(TargetFileName) to $(TargetName)d$(TargetExt) for debug mode and it worked. Question can be marked as resolved